# Possible Homebrew and Rubie issues after the installation of RVM on Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew, rvm

I've installed RVM via the line offered on the rvm.io homepage:

```
curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --rails --autolibs=enabled
```

In order of the installation process RVM automatically installed Homebrew and started to go on with Ruby 2.0 which actually failed and terminated the whole process. Actually RVM itself works. I was also able to install Ruby 1.9.3 without any problems afterwards. On the "rvm rubies" command i get the following output:

```
=* ruby-1.9.3-p392 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.0.0-p0 [ broken ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
# * - default
```

So is it the savest way to just remove the broken Ruby 2.0 installation with the aid of RVM?

But the thing which worries me a little bit more is the Homebrew installation. When i run the "brew doctor" command i get the following warning:

```
Warning: Your Homebrew is not installed to /usr/local
You can install Homebrew anywhere you want, but some brews may only build
correctly if you install in /usr/local. Sorry!
```

on "which brew" i get:

```
 /Users/rpk/.rvm/bin/brew
```

So is it ok that Homebrew resides in the RVM folder or should Homebrew be deleted and reinstalled in the recommended location? Or is RVM able to handle things that Homebrew is able to install every brew in that RVM location? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
which brew
/Users/$USER/.rvm/bin/brew

rvm use system
which brew
/usr/local/bin/brew

brew install <problematic_formulae>
```

To get back...

```
rvm use 2.0.0
```